# opening file name from user input in assembly

Tags: string, file, assembly, input

I can't open file with string from user input. When I'm giving print input string, it's ok. Can you help me?

```
vstupz db 100
       db 0
subor  db 103DUP(?)
handler_sub DW ?


mov dx,offset vstupz
mov ah,0ah
int 21h

mov al,0
mov ah,3dh
mov dx, offset subor
int 21h
mov handler_sub,AX
```

When I haven't `subor db 103DUP(?)` but `subor db"subor.txt",` it works ....

Thanks

Comment: `int 21h/0ah` gives you a carriage return-terminated string. `int 21h/3dh` expects a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: but how can i fix it???

Comment: By replacing the string terminator after you've read the string.

Comment: Scanning for a given value in memory and writing to memory are both basic operations. You should probably read a book or tutorial so that you understand the basics of x86 assembly.